# Extra (false) mouse click with filedialog when a file is selected

Tags: tkinter

My application contains a lot of Checkbuttons and filedialog is used to load various type of files. I found that after a file is selected with filedialog.askopenfilename() there is an extra mouse click event at a location right underneath the current mouse cursor. This mouse click event is the click that selects the file I think. The problem is if the current mouse cursor location after the file is select is right on top of a Checkbutton the Checkbutton will get toggled falsely. Is there a way to eliminate this extra mouse click?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def callback(event):
    print("clicked at", event.x, event.y)

def open_file():
    fname=tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(1024,600)

root.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

tk.Button(root,text='File action',command=open_file).grid(row=0,column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

The above code is verified under python 3.5.3. Every mouse click will be displayed at the terminal. A click on the button marked "File action" triggers a filedialog. It can be seen if a file is selected the terminal shows an extra mouse click (supposedly associated with the mouse click to select the file). If the filedialog is canceled by clicking "X" or "Cancel" there is no such extra mouse click.

Comment: I know this is a late reply to your question but what would be wrong about disabling all of your checkboxes as soon as a modal dialog opens (e.g. in javascript i would create an overlay in between modal dialog and rest of the window to capture just that) and only enable them after the dialog has been closed? As a rough-fix you could also use a minimal sleep interval (`window.after` functionality) to ensure you capture that. If you find a different solution you are most welcome to share that one as well.